# Using github CLI (cli/cli) to deploy repo

Tags: github, centos7, github-cli

Trying to deploy internal development from GitHub to a Centos 7 webserver, running into 2 issues.

Firstly, I'm using PHP and need to deploy the class files to a folder that is not `/var/www/html/`, where I have cloned the repository to using
`cd /var/www/`
`gh repo clone linkto/repo html` (this may be the wrong thing to do).

Secondly, Prompting me to think that I've done the first part wrong, when trying to use `gh repo sync linkto/repo` i get the error `can't determine source repository for GitUser/home because repository is not fork` leading me to believe that instead of cloning I need to fork it. My intention here is that no code would ever be changed on the server-side just updated on GitHub then push to the server. Am I trying to do too much with GitHub? or am I trying to do it wrong?

**EDIT:**
doing `cd /var/www/html/` `gh repo fork` `gh repo sync` and setting a remote back to the origin has solved the second issue

Thanks,

Comment: You might want to rethink Centos. Check Centos End of Life

Comment: @Wakka Its only a temporary test deployment of the GitHub workflow, I just want to get the process working, will all translate over to 8/Stream

Comment: Cent OS 8 is gone. It hut EOL just before xmas. And Centos Stream is not suitable for a webserver delivering production. Just a heads up on that. It's not a replacement for Cetnos linux, It's a development & testing platform for RHEL.

Comment: On your git issue, Number one. Am I right in saying you just want to store your classes outside of the web facing folders?

Comment: @Wakka Yeah, off the top of my head in /usr/share/php/ I know I can do this manually, and potentially with a symbolic link that apache doesn't have permission for.

Comment: personally depending on the project and what they are I would either drop it in `/etc` or `/opt`. If its just scripts and what not I'd tend to go for the `/opt` directory and if it's a more robust system like say maybe a CMS or quite a technical api I'd go for the `/etc` directory. I'm not a great fan of having php files anywhere near apaches directories. I also don't feel that `/var` is the right directory for them either being a spool directory.

Comment: @Wakka Ok, I'll look into where might be a better place for them for my use case. Do you have any pointers for being able to take the root folder in the repo `classes` and have it be synced to a different location when using `gh repo sync` so development can be done with the classes in the same repo as the rest of the site but have it split them out when deploying, alternatively can run a script to sync then cut/paste.

Comment: I do this using pipelines in bit bucket. If that's an option for you. but there is a way to do it with just git and a folder in linux and a scrpt. There is also Git hooks https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks. which is probably what you're after. There's hook policies specifically for server side

Comment: @Wakka That looks like it. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: no worries mate have a good one

Answer (score 0):

In
`cd /var/www/html/`

**Running once to setup:**

`gh repo fork` with a remote set to the origin

**Each time to update:**

`gh repo sync` setting the base repository each time to update

Then using
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks
a server-side post-receive hook to move the classes directory to the desired location